# Bounty is subtracted before awarding?

Tags: discussion, bounty

Today I set a bounty on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29122444/kml-file-rendering-issue-smooth-text) and I noticed that the bounty had already been subtracted from my imaginary Internet points even though there is no answer, therefore no bounty has been awarded.

The only reason I noticed is because I was on another question for which I was awarded the correct answer but the points did not show up in the little green bubble at the top of the page. I clicked the candles at the top of the page and saw this:

[image: bounty subtracted already]

I have only done the bounty thing a couple of times but never took notice of this. Is this what happens when a bounty is proposed?

Comment: The bounty is as an advertisement in the newspaper. It is paid for before any sales generated from it are made. You are "paying" for the space on the featured list and the added visibility that brings, not an answer.

Comment: I found the sentence from a link in an answer below: *"The bounty award will be subtracted from your reputation when the bounty is started, not when it is awarded." From [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bounties are always subtracted from your rep balance as soon as it is initiated - it is, as MichaelT stated, an advertisement.

It is not refunded at all (there have been a few discussions about this).

Also, if it is not awarded by the OP, then half will be auto awarded to an answer with a score of +2 or more.

See [How does the bounty system work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: Thanks! I see the one sentence blurb in the third FAQ _ "The bounty award will be subtracted from your reputation when the bounty is started, not when it is awarded."

Answer (score 7):

The bounty is an *advertisement*; you get attention for the post while the bounty is active because the question is listed separately and those that answer it could perhaps get a price. But it is the *attention* that counts here.

> **Come and see my question, all and yonder. Best answer could win a prize! Roll up! Roll up!**

As such, you pay the bounty *up front*. If no answers are eligible you still got your attention, after all.